# Nestjs - What is the correct way to create a DTO file to transform a nested json object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, dto

I am trying to create a DTO file to transform the values and save a Document.

```js
export class CreateProductDto {
  readonly pricing: {
    readonly list: number;
  } 
}

async create(@Body() createProductDto: CreateProductDto) {
  console.log(createProductDto);
  console.log(createProductDto.pricing.list); 
}
```

```js
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

export const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  pricing: {
    list: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
});
```

But the value of princing.list is **undefined**.

What is the correct way to do this in NestJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please go through this [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation)
in your case your dto is going to be

```
import { IsNumber, IsObject } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';
export class ListDto {
  @IsNumber()
  readonly list: number
}

export class CreateProductDto {
  @IsObject()
  @ValidateNested() @Type(() => ListDto)
  readonly pricing: ListDto
}
```

in your main.ts

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
```